# script load script ads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code html js css as

```js
$('.list li:nth-child(4)').after('<li class="new-elem"></li>');
```

```css
li.new-elem {width:336px; height:280px; background:#faa}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="list">
  <li>Thi is list post 01</li>
  <li>Thi is list post 01</li>
  <li>Thi is list post 01</li>
  <li>Thi is list post 01</li>
  <li>Thi is list post 01</li>
</article>
```

Now how to insert script

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<iframe src='http://www.myadscode.com/ads/banneriframe.php?pchsh=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&t=336x280&cb=" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*99999) + new Date().getTime()) + "' style='width:336px;height:280px;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>");</script>
```

as:

```
$('.list li:nth-child(4)').after('<li class="new-elem"><script type="text/javascript">document.write("<iframe src='http://www.myadscode.com/ads/banneriframe.php?pchsh=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&t=336x280&cb=" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*99999) + new Date().getTime()) + "' style='width:336px;height:280px;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>");</script></li>');
```

This is error code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 $('.list li').eq('4').after('<li class="new-elem">My script ads here</li>');
```

Add url like this

```
$('.list li').eq('4').after("<li class="new-elem"><iframe src='http://www.myadscode.com/ads/banneriframe.php?pchsh=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&t=3‌​36x280&cb=" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*99999) + new Date().getTime()) + "' style='width:336px;height:280px;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe></li>");
```

Instead of

```
$('.list li:nth-child(4)').after('<li class="new-elem">My script ads here</li>');
```

Comment: you need to add the iframe url after 4 li ?

Comment: eq() function starts from `0` so if you need after 3rd li u need to use like  `$('.list li').eq('2')` @QBW

Comment: the error is about the ad page.did u check the code is right for ads ? please run the iframe link alone.you may get the idea about it

Comment: now my proplem: http://jsfiddle.net/sfk5t5u4/3/ => show li ads. http://jsfiddle.net/sfk5t5u4/ show li but dont show ads? you have Any idea, help me.

Comment: http://www.myads.com/ads/banneriframe.php?pchsh=xxxx&amp;t=336x280&amp;cb=1424850310611 run the above link that was an ad link its doesnt work and now check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sfk5t5u4/4/ its works bcz the link is not broken

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function() { 
     var l = $('.list li').length-1;
        $('.list li').eq(l).after('<li class="new-elem">My script ads here</li>');
     });
     <!-- ========= Or ======= -->
      $(function() { 
         $('.list li').eq('4').after('<li class="new-elem">My script ads here</li>');
 });
```